# Regex: Select first specific word occurrences inside enclosed elements

Tags: java, regex

I have a String containing url paths:

```
...
/test/section/1.png
"/test/section/test/2.png" "/test/section/test/2.png"
(/test/section/test/3.png)
...
```

I want to get all first "test" occurrences of enclosed url elements in quotes or parenthesis.

Until now i have accomplished to get the first occurance of each String with the '"' or '(':

```
(\(|\")(\/orbeon\/)
```

---

*Matches are presented with **bold***.

Current output:

> /test/section/1.png
>
> **"/test/** section/test/2.png" **"/test/** section/test/2.png"
>
> **(/test/** section/test/3.png)

---

Desired output:

> /test/section/1.png
>
> " **/test/** section/test/2.png" " **/test/** section/test/2.png"
>
> ( **/test/** section/test/3.png)

How can i exclude the char before matching word?

Caution! I want only the first word occurance of each enclosed url path:

Corner case: **/test/** section/test/2.png

*Using this regex with java*

Comment: Just get the `matcher.group(2)` value. Or use a [`(?<=[(\"])/orbeon/`](https://regex101.com/r/FKTd4T/1)  regex.

Comment: Make your comment an answer to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `(\(|\")(\/orbeon\/)` regex matches `(` or `"` into Group 1 and `/orbeon/` into Group 2.

Thus, when you execute `matcher.find()`, you will need to access Group 2 using `matcher.group(2)`.

Else, use a lookbehind: `Pattern.compile("(?<=[(\"])/orbeon/")`, and you will have access to the necessary text with `matcher.group()` or `matcher.group(0)`. The `(?<=[(\"])` positive lookbehind will assert the presence of `(` or `"` before `/orbeon/`, and if not present, there won't be any match.

Comment: it first occurence of '/test/' is always at the beginning, its easy. but if it's in the middle, it can get tricky

Comment: @JánStibila: If you explain what you mean, I will adjust the above solution.

Comment: "/something/test/blabla/test/this" - match first /test/ occurence

Comment: you cant use lookbehind, because it has to be fixed length. and remember there can be multiple paths in a row, some enclosed, some don't

Comment: @JánStibila: you mean the string is `String s = "\"/something/test/blabla/test/this\"";` and the `/test/` must be matched because there is a `"` before? Then you are right, a [capturing approach should be used](http://ideone.com/sOudVy). Or, if there may be several matches in one string, [this approach should also work](http://ideone.com/I2UcXk).